# Why do I get different result using log() function in C?

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, raspberry-pi3

Here is a simple example of `log()` function test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 2;
    printf("int a = %d, log((double)a) = %g, log(2.0) = %g\n", a, log((double)a), log(2.0));
    return 0;
}
```

I get difference on Raspberry Pi 3 and Ubuntu16.04:

**arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc**

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -mfloat-abi=soft -march=armv7-a  foo.c -o foo -lm
$ ./foo 
int a = 2, log((double)a) = 5.23028e-314, log(2.0) = 0.693147
```

**arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc**

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -march=armv7-a  foo.c -o foo -lm
$ ./foo 
int a = 2, log((double)a) = 0.693147, log(2.0) = 0.693147
```

**gcc**

```
$ gcc foo.c -o foo -lm
$ ./foo 
int a = 2, log((double)a) = 0.693147, log(2.0) = 0.693147
```

Comment: Try adding some code that does FP math.  Some compilers with such trivial programs do not well work with FP and `printf()`.

Comment: As far as I know: raspbian does not support soft-floats because it is a hardfloat distribution. A program compiled with soft-float might even run but might not be correct as is the case here where it spits out a denormal number.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi your comment looks like it should be an answer (along with the remark that the compiler can and does compute `log(2.0)` at compile-time as part of the **constant folding** optimization, making that one seem to work.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi soft float vs hard float is not necessarily a distro thing.  It would not have compiled otherwise.  It is mostly a compiler thing, depends on how you build as to where the math is done and how it is connected and/or built into the program.  can certainly build your own toolchain on top of a distro kind of proving the point that the distro is not a factor.  hard float requires the processor to support it but soft float only requires the toolchain and connected libraries.

Comment: what happens when you try different settings with the same compiler rather than changing two things at once?

Comment: If you think this is soft vs hard float then what other experiments have you done?

Comment: along with the theory this has something to do with the operating system, what order did you run these programs?  what if you run them in a different order, mix in programs that call log or other functions with different operands.  does it change the results?  can you get the results to change or do they always give the same results no matter what?

Comment: @old_timer The default toolchain for raspbian is hard-float, you have to change it activel. It seems to be that *curious behaviour* is the norm if you mix them up. A short Google search gave a handfull of people wondering about why nothing happens if you mix hard/soft-float while on the other side some odd results showed up.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi I understand your point, but the OP results are not consistent with that theory.

Comment: @old_timer it is quite typical for "undefined behaviour" to give inconsistent results.

Comment: When I use '-static' option on arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc, the answer seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

The standard distribution of Raspbian uses the hardware floating point support of the Raspberry Pi ([Raspbian FAQ](https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianFAQ#What_is_Raspbian.3F)) which is not fully compatible with the different approach of using a software library to emulate floating point computation using integers only.

You can tell the type of your Raspbian distribution by looking for the directory `/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf` for the hard-float version and `/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi` ([How can I tell...](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4677/how-can-i-tell-if-i-am-using-the-hard-float-or-the-soft-float-version-of-debian)) for the soft-float one.

As Pascal Cuoq noted in one of the comments to this question, it might be of interest to know that the reason for the correct result of `log(2.0)` in all examples is called *constant folding*. The compiler is allowed to compute every result at compile time—if possible—for optimization purposes. This might be an unwanted behaviour if you have for example different rounding modes in your code. GCC has `-frounding-math` to switch of constant folding (among other things), although it might not catch everything, so be careful here.

Comment: there is a far simpler answer for one to be correct and the other not as pointed out.  there so far has been no work by the OP on this problem, and this answer has no work either, needs to show how these things can and cannot happen without any external links.  external links in answers are useless at stackoverflow when they go away or change the answer is no longer useful.  not hard to show how the soft float can result like that, have both answers the same or different, likewise to get softfloat to actually work on this platform.  None of this work has been done on either side.

Comment: If nothing else is going to be done then lets just close this as too broad and move on.

Answer (score 0):

Not able to repeat the issue.  Where is your disassembly to show the value fed to printf?

```
#include <math.h>
double fun1 ( void )
{
    return(log(2));
}
double fun2 ( void )
{
    return(log(2.0));
}


00000000 <fun1>:
   0:   e30309ef    movw    r0, #14831  ; 0x39ef
   4:   e3021e42    movw    r1, #11842  ; 0x2e42
   8:   e34f0efa    movt    r0, #65274  ; 0xfefa
   c:   e3431fe6    movt    r1, #16358  ; 0x3fe6
  10:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000014 <fun2>:
  14:   e30309ef    movw    r0, #14831  ; 0x39ef
  18:   e3021e42    movw    r1, #11842  ; 0x2e42
  1c:   e34f0efa    movt    r0, #65274  ; 0xfefa
  20:   e3431fe6    movt    r1, #16358  ; 0x3fe6
  24:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000000 <fun1>:
   0:   ed9f 0b01   vldr    d0, [pc, #4]    ; 8 <fun1+0x8>
   4:   4770        bx  lr
   6:   bf00        
   8:   fefa39ef    
   c:   3fe62e42    

00000010 <fun2>:
  10:   ed9f 0b01   vldr    d0, [pc, #4]    ; 18 <fun2+0x8>
  14:   4770        bx  lr
  16:   bf00        
  18:   fefa39ef    
  1c:   3fe62e42    

0000000000000000 <fun1>:
   0:   f2 0f 10 05 00 00 00    movsd  0x0(%rip),%xmm0        # 8 <fun1+0x8>
   7:   00 
   8:   c3                      retq   

0000000000000010 <fun2>:
  10:   f2 0f 10 05 00 00 00    movsd  0x0(%rip),%xmm0        # 18 <fun2+0x8>
  17:   00 
  18:   c3                      retq   


0000000000000000 <.LC0>:
   0:   ef                
   1:   39 fa             
   3:   fe 42 2e          
   6:   e6 3f
```

Now causing an int to float conversion vs building in the float version (2) vs (2.0) as well as adding in (2.0F).  Compile time or runtime can cause differences.

Start by eliminating the printf, divide this problem in half, am I seeing some printf thing or not printf thing.  then is this a compile time thing or is this a runtime thing, is this a hard float thing or a soft float thing.  Is this a c library thing or not a C library thing.

What if anything have you done so far to debug this?

Eventually someone is going to link the "whatever programmer should know about floating point" whether it applies or not...

EDIT

```
#include <math.h>
double fun ( void )
{
    return(log(2.0));
}

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e52db004    push    {fp}        ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
   4:   e28db000    add fp, sp, #0
   8:   e30329ef    movw    r2, #14831  ; 0x39ef
   c:   e34f2efa    movt    r2, #65274  ; 0xfefa
  10:   e3023e42    movw    r3, #11842  ; 0x2e42
  14:   e3433fe6    movt    r3, #16358  ; 0x3fe6
  18:   ec432b17    vmov    d7, r2, r3
  1c:   eeb00b47    vmov.f64    d0, d7
  20:   e24bd000    sub sp, fp, #0
  24:   e49db004    pop {fp}        ; (ldr fp, [sp], #4)
  28:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e52db004    push    {fp}        ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
   4:   e28db000    add fp, sp, #0
   8:   e30329ef    movw    r2, #14831  ; 0x39ef
   c:   e34f2efa    movt    r2, #65274  ; 0xfefa
  10:   e3023e42    movw    r3, #11842  ; 0x2e42
  14:   e3433fe6    movt    r3, #16358  ; 0x3fe6
  18:   e1a00002    mov r0, r2
  1c:   e1a01003    mov r1, r3
  20:   e24bd000    sub sp, fp, #0
  24:   e49db004    pop {fp}        ; (ldr fp, [sp], #4)
  28:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

well there goes the notion of constant folding explaining why to calls to log() give vastly different results.  (arguably a different version of the toolchain (or different command line arguments) you could just get lucky, so far we dont know what version of the toolchains, build options, etc were used to be able to repeat this).

EDIT 2

```
#include <math.h>
double fun ( void )
{
    return(log(2));
}

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e52db004    push    {fp}        ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
   4:   e28db000    add fp, sp, #0
   8:   e30329ef    movw    r2, #14831  ; 0x39ef
   c:   e34f2efa    movt    r2, #65274  ; 0xfefa
  10:   e3023e42    movw    r3, #11842  ; 0x2e42
  14:   e3433fe6    movt    r3, #16358  ; 0x3fe6
  18:   ec432b17    vmov    d7, r2, r3
  1c:   eeb00b47    vmov.f64    d0, d7
  20:   e24bd000    sub sp, fp, #0
  24:   e49db004    pop {fp}        ; (ldr fp, [sp], #4)
  28:   e12fff1e    bx  lr




00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e52db004    push    {fp}        ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
   4:   e28db000    add fp, sp, #0
   8:   e30329ef    movw    r2, #14831  ; 0x39ef
   c:   e34f2efa    movt    r2, #65274  ; 0xfefa
  10:   e3023e42    movw    r3, #11842  ; 0x2e42
  14:   e3433fe6    movt    r3, #16358  ; 0x3fe6
  18:   e1a00002    mov r0, r2
  1c:   e1a01003    mov r1, r3
  20:   e24bd000    sub sp, fp, #0
  24:   e49db004    pop {fp}        ; (ldr fp, [sp], #4)
  28:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

around 60 seconds worth of work to contemplate constant folding maybe being a factor, so far it doesnt apply, but there is potential dumb luck there, but the same dumb luck could/would apply to both calls to log

A few seconds of work by the OP to disassemble that program would quickly cover this side topic.